# How to specify event_type in workflow, when triggering via a repository dispatch event

Tags: github-api, github-actions

I am trying to setup a workflow to be triggered via Github Actions' "Repository Dispatch event", as specified [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/events-that-trigger-workflows#external-events) and [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-a-repository-dispatch-event). As input to the API request, it specifies that i need to include an event-type, as a custom webhook event name.

I however also want to be able to use this event-type in my workflow, so that i can have multiple workflows triggered by the `repository_dispatch` option, each triggered by their own event type.

As specified in the section about [how to use webhook event triggers](https://help.github.com/en/articles/events-that-trigger-workflows#webhook-events), i have tried using the types field, when declaring when my workflow should trigger (see code). This however only results in nothing being triggered. If i omit the types field, the workflow triggers.

Here is my workflow

```
name: External trigger

on:
  repository_dispatch
    types: external_test

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Say hi
        run: echo "Hi!"
```

and here is the API request payload:

```
{
    "event_type": "external_test"
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `:` after `repository_dispatch`. The yaml doesn't look valid.

Comment: @peterevans Thanks, that fixed it. If you post it as an answer, i'll mark it as the answer. Apparently i can't do that with comments.

Comment: Good to hear that fixed it. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Missing a `:` after `repository_dispatch` so the yaml is not valid.

```
name: External trigger

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: external_test
```